# How to delete any PNGs in a directory smaller than 100x100 in BASH?

Tags: bash, png, delete-file

I have a directory containing many PNG clip art. I need to delete all that are smaller than 100x100 px. How can I delete them?

Comment: How do you want to handle images that are 75x200 and other similar size situations?

Comment: If width or height are smaller than 100px, it should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `file` on an image, it gives you that image's dimensions:

```
$ file yourimage.png
your_directory/yourimage.png    PNG image data, 512 x 512, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Just parse out the numeric value and determine how you want to keep or delete the image based on the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in `ls`
do
  for i in `file $f | cut -f 2 -d ',' | cut -f 2,4 -d ' '` # hsize vsize
  do
    if [[ $i < 100 ]]
    then
      rm -rf $f # try echo $i for the dry run
    fi
  done
done
```